# Call to DevOps SE moderators: migrating unanswered DevOps questions to our site

Tags: discussion, support

As I've found out, it's possible under certain conditions to migrate unanswered DevOps questions to our site as lower boundary of the eligibility to do so.

Say migration is from *source* to *target*.

- (1) *Any* user with 3K+ reputation at *source* is eligible to access the "Migrate to site.." [option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site) (this is the case for at least some of our moderators and SO)
- (2) *Target* that is a pre-defined site from the list of sites which might have been defined before our site existed. => if this still applies, migration is not possible.

As of 2017, the "flag question" option displayed the "off-topic/Migrate to site.." option if you had 3K+ reputation<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

While (1) is easy, if (2) applies, our moderators would need to elaborate how our site can be put on that list.

If this is solved, migrating a couple of questions a day could:

- deliver answers to unanswered questions
- fill up the gap we need to qualify from Beta

Additionally, there might be "too old" questions older than current 60 days limit, which might be worth re-asking or finding ways to override the rule seen from our site's perspective.

<sup><sub>1</sub></sup> As you can see, at that time "Software Engineering SE" was called "Programmers SE". :-)

Comment: I heard on another SE that betas cannot be added to the list.

Comment: oh no, that is really too bad!.. :-/ Also I've seen that the startup SE has been opened and closed two times with overall very good metrics except the average number of questions. A pity I'm locked at the central Meta.

Comment: @030 an update from SO moderator: "Steps: Find good (well-asked) questions on SO that have been closed (we don’t migrate questions that are on-topic for SO: on sites with overlapping scope, it is asker’s choice), and flag these questions for diamond moderator attention. Make sure to mention that DevOps agrees with the requested migration (maybe link this Meta question). If there’s a large batch at once, maybe ping me with a PasteBin or something containing links." https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392666/1800-unanswered-devops-questions-at-so?noredirect=1#comment748090_392666

Comment: @030 a quick shot - 
there are 134 closed SO questions matching keyword *DevOps* https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=devops+closed%3A1 and 220 matching keyword *Kubernetes*. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=kuberbetes+closed%3A1 (both sets might overlap of course)   

According to linguistics studies of meaning, it could indeed be that some questions on SO could appear on-topic but not well focused for people having no deeper knowledge in say Kubernetes. At DevOps there might be a higher chance that somebody enthusiastic with Kubernetes sees the question, and "decodes" the problem deeper.